# how to post data to particular url?

Tags: python

I want to `post some data` in the particular url say `http://localhost:8000/postme/`. But I have know form yet. So, I want to test it without any form. So, How can I post data to the url without any form? I want to see the response to the web browser.

Answer (score 5):

You can do an Ajax post using jQuery. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) page for the API.

Or for Python, you can use `httplib`. See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) page for the API. Here's an example:

```
>>> import httplib, urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
...            "Accept": "text/plain"}
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("musi-cal.mojam.com:80")
>>> conn.request("POST", "/cgi-bin/query", params, headers)
>>> response = conn.getresponse()
>>> print response.status, response.reason
200 OK
>>> data = response.read()
>>> conn.close()
```

Comment: but this this will not show the response to the web browser. I want to see the response to the web browser.

Comment: @ajax-ie: Then just add a `print data` before `conn.close()`.

Comment: This is not my query. I want to print that data in to the browser. For this i tried import webbroser and then webbroser.open(url, data) but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl` for this:

```
curl -F "name=jonesy" http://localhost:8080/postme
```

Or you can use the twill python module (which also has a shell interface):

```
twill-sh
jonesy$ twill-sh

-= Welcome to twill! =-

current page:  *empty page* 
>> go 'http://www.google.com' 
==> at http://www.google.com
current page: http://www.google.com
>> showforms

Form name=f (#1)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     hl                       hidden    (None)       en 
2     source                   hidden    (None)       hp 
3     ie                       hidden    (None)       ISO-8859-1 
4     q                        text      (None)        
5  1  btnG                     submit    (None)       Google Search 
6  2  btnI                     submit    (None)       I'm Feeling Lucky 

>> fv f q 'python'
current page: http://www.google.com
>> submit
Note: submit is using submit button: name="btnG", value="Google Search"

current page: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=python&btnG=Google+Search
>> save_html
(Using filename 'search')
current page: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=python&btnG=Google+Search
>> showlinks
Links:

0. Images ==> http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=python&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi
1. Videos ==> http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=python&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbs=vid:1&source=og&sa=N&tab=wv
2. Maps ==> http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=python&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wl
3. News ==> http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=python&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbs=nws:1&source=og&sa=N&tab=wn
4. Shopping ==> http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=python&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbs=shop:1&source=og&sa=N&tab=wf
5. Gmail ==> http://mail.google.com/mail/?hl=en&tab=wm
```

....the links go on forever, but you get the point. You can use twill in the shell like I did here, or those commands can be called as methods in the twill.commands module in a python script.

Of course, you can leave the twill shell and open the file 'search' (in this example) to see the actual html that went to the browser.